# Two select queries with count to one query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have two queries to count data:

```
SELECT x.Id, COUNT( DISTINCT y.Id )
FROM X x
INNER JOIN Y y ON x.Id = y.otherId


SELECT x.Id, COUNT( DISTINCT z.Id )
FROM X x
INNER JOIN Z z ON x.Id = z.otherId
```

Both queries return the right value when executing separated.

But I would like to combine those queries to one single query:

```
SELECT x.Id, COUNT( DISTINCT y.Id ), COUNT( DISTINCT z.Id )
FROM X x
INNER JOIN Y y ON x.Id = y.otherId
INNER JOIN Z z ON x.Id = z.otherId
```

When I do this, the both counts are wrong when compared to the separately executed queries.

Why is this happening, I am really confused. The solution might be simple, but I really don't have any clue at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `inner join` is filtering out values that don't match in *both* tables.  To do what you want, use `left outer join`:

```
SELECT x.Id, COUNT( DISTINCT y.Id ), COUNT( DISTINCT z.Id )
FROM X x
LEFT JOIN Y y ON x.Id = y.otherId
LEFT JOIN Z z ON x.Id = z.otherId ;
```

I caution against this approach because it produces an intermediate result that is the cartesian product of the number of matching values in the two tables (for a given value of `x.ID`).  Instead, you can use subqueries.  Here is an example using nested subqueries

```
select x.id,
       (select count(distinct y.id) from y where x.id = y.otherId),
       (select count(distinct z.id) from z where x.id = z.otherid)
from x;
```

Comment: Hello why is inner join filtering out values that don't match in both tables? For example I am using x.Id = y.otherId, this should get the matched values, doesn't it?

Comment: @y451n . . . Some `x.id` have matches in the `y` table; some have matches in the `z` table.  Some in both, but some only in one.  With the inner join, you only get the matches in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` is like an intersection. The first query is counting all distinct `y.id` that have `y.otherId` in table `x`, but not necessary in `z`. The second is all distinct `z.id` where `z.otherId` is in `x`, but not necessarily in `y`. The third, combined query will be all `y.id` such that `y.otherId` is in x AND in `z.otherId`, and vice versa.

If you want both counts, you can always just put them together with `UNION`, though it will put your two answers in different rows, as opposed to different columns.